# javascript inheritance for namespace

Tags: javascript, oop

i am new to oop in javascript.

```
var obj1 = {
  name : 'honda',
  getName : function(){
   console.log(this.name);
  }
}

var obj2 = {name:'maruti'};
```

I want to access `getName` of `obj1` with scope of `obj2`, like `obj2.getName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
obj1.getName.call(obj2);
```

As @roland said, you can also use `.apply(obj2, [arr of args])` if you want to provide an array of arguments to the method.

EDIT:
If you want to import all `obj1` methods into `obj2`, you can do that with pure JavaScript:

```
for (var m in obj1) {
    // if you want to copy obj1's attributes, remove this line
    if (obj1[m] instanceof Function) {
        obj[2][m] = obj1[m];
    }
}
```

Or you can do it with jQuery:

```
$.extend(obj2, obj1);
```

Comment: i want output to be honda using obj2 scope.

Comment: @user2087122 why would you want that?

Comment: how to inherit obj1 in obj2?

Comment: if you want honda, then what is obj2 even for?

Comment: @user2087122 - asking for the answer to be 'honda' in the scope of `obj2` simply makes no sense.  You either get the name of obj2 in obj2's scope or the name of obj1 in the scope of obj1.  The name of obj2 is `"mauruti"`.  That's what the answer is in the scope of `obj2` unless you change the name of `obj2` to be `"honda"`.

Comment: lets say there are some other methods defined inside obj1, and we want to use all those methods/properties. how do we achive this?

Answer (score 0):

If are looking to use `obj1` as a template for creating new objects, you can use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to do this.

```
var obj1 = {
  name : 'honda',
  getName : function(){
   console.log(this.name);
  }
}

var obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
obj2.name = 'bob';
obj2.getName(); // outputs 'bob'
```